# Forward a binary file from form to remote server using curl

Tags: php, curl, php-5.5

The following script works:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $filename);


echo exec('curl -X POST --data-binary @' . $filename . ' http://remote.api:8888/index/add');
```

Following doesn't:-

We will be disabling exec() soon and will be doing plenty of hardening so the above solution will not work.

I tried the following:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $filename);
$filetype = $_FILES['file']['type'];
$ch = curl_init('http://remote.api/index/add');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 8888);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
$cFile = curl_file_create($filename, $filetype, $_FILES['file']['name']); // php5.5+
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ['file' => $cFile]);
$x = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

The server does not respond to this workaround.

What am I missing? Please note I am using php 5.5 thus curl_create_file

Thank you for all the help :)

Comment: What does curl_exec() return? What do you get if you output the result of curl_getinfo($ch)?

Comment: size upload - size download - as in .. nothing goes wrong..

Comment: not sure what you want me to do? exec returns 1 but since I have returntransfer it gives me an error which api is supposed to be throwing upon not receiving the file...